# How to set background color of slider button in jQuery mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have a list of slider buttons implemented with jQuery Mobile:

```
<li class="settings_item" id="news" data-icon="false" style="background: white">
    <label for="news_item" class="label_slider">Show News</label>
     <select id="news_item" data-role="slider" data-theme="d">
         <option value="off">Off</option>
         <option value="on" selected>On</option>
     </select>
</li>
```

I set the data-theme="d". I like this data theme but the background color of the slider button in this theme is blue by default. Can I make it red instead?

Comment: Just this one or across the whole theme?

Comment: @Popnoodles Whole theme.

Comment: Ok. Your question is about CSS not javascript. Tags updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using jQM version 1.3.x, you cannot set different active colors directly in the theme, but you can override them in CSS:

```
.ui-slider .ui-btn-active {
    background-color: rgb(226, 155, 44);
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(226, 155, 44), rgb(206, 135, 24));
    border-color: brown;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/R2qk5/)**